# What was the default font of gEdit on Ubuntu 10.04 (lucid)?

Tags: 10.04, lubuntu, 14.04, fonts, gedit

I just upgraded from **Ubuntu 10.04** to **Lubuntu 14.04** and I installed the latest version of all the programs that I had on my previous computer.

I installed the latest **gEdit 3.10.4** version and a lot has changed from the previous version I had on **lucid** (2.3). I really liked the font of the old lucid version and I'm uncomfortable with the new version having a new different font from the other. So, I would like the font of the current version to be that of the old gEdit version's.

Does anyone know the default font used by **gEdit 2.3** version of **Ubuntu 10.04** ?

You can see screenshots of the old version below:

[image]

Comment: That looks to me like DejaVu Sans Mono.

Comment: ...or try Inconsolata. Really a great monospaced font.

Comment: @Jos I tried it, but there is a slight difference from the font on the image (http://open.subinsb.com/cdn/img/ex_code2 ) and `DejaVu Sans Mono`. @Ramano I don't want to try anything. I really like the font to become what it was.

Comment: Are you sure? This is what I get: http://imgur.com/KrBM1Lu. If there are any differences, I don't see them.

Comment: Well, from 10.04 to 14.04 the font rendering engine has probably changed a lot. So there could be a small difference in hinting or subsampling, especially in high resolution displays.

Comment: @Jos I get a different style : http://i.imgur.com/onh7Tbw.png and I double checked that I set the font to `DejaVu Sans Mono`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default gedit font in Ubuntu 10.04 was 'DejaVu Sans Mono', and its size was 10pts.

Comment: Why the downvotes? It is a reasonable answer. If the downvoters knows better, please post your answer.

Comment: @Rmano: I originally made a mistake, and said the font was 'Monospace', then I remembered that Monospace was mapped to DejaVu Sans Mono, so I changed the answer. It's now 100% correct.

Comment: @Eric I get a different style : i.imgur.com/onh7Tbw.png and I double checked that I set the font to `DejaVu Sans Mono`.

Comment: Looks to me like you haven't turned antialiasing on. But it is the same font.

Comment: @Jos I have turned antialiasing on using gnome tweak tool and I'm using lubuntu 14.04 But still the font isn't that of the old 10.04 version.